# wp_get_current_user->user login returns %20 for spaces

Tags: functions, terms

I’m creating a custom form in CF7 and want to autocreate a link in the table to the users id via a shortcode plugin that does the business in CF7.  It works fine when the user login has only one word. However when the user adds a space in their user name, the return adds a %20. Unfortunately, when the user url is generated, it replaces the spaces with a -
For example, I have a test in the Artist CPT called Artist Test (User Id). The CPT address is https://mysite/artist/artist-test
I’d like the link created by the shortcode below to create the same url. However, the url returned is //mysite/artist/artist%20test which then doesn’t work. I’ve tried to use urldecode to no avail.

```
/*
 * Current User link shortcode
 * Use like so: [current_user_link] This is displayed only if current user is logged in.
 */

add_shortcode( 'current_user_link', 'wppbc_current_user_link' );
function wppbc_current_user_link( $atts, $content ) {
   if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

      $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
      $id = $current_user->user_login;

      return "<a href='https://mysite/artist/{$id}'>Custom Page Link</a>";
   }

   return ;
```

Answer (score 1):

`%20` is how spaces are represented in URLs/links. It is not present in the `user_login` property. The browser is adding it because you've put in in an href attribute.

How are you creating this artist CPT? If you're just creating it with the artist name as the title, then the slug isn't going to necessarily be the username. It will be sanitised into a valid slug the same way post titles are normally turned into slugs. If you then try to create a link using the user login then you're naively ignoring the process that creates the slug and expecting them to be the same.

If you want to find the post that has the title that matches the username, then you should query for a post based on the title, and then properly get its permalink:

```
function wppbc_current_user_link( $atts, $content ) {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return;
    }

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_login   = $current_user->user_login;

    $post = get_page_by_title( $user_login, 'OBJECT', 'artist' ); // Substitute 'artist' with your CPT's name.

    if ( $post ) {
        $url = esc_url( get_the_permalink( $post ) );

        return "<a href='{$url}'>Custom Page Link</a>";
    }
}
```

A more resilient solution, though, would be to save a reference to the post ID as user meta when the post is created. That way you don't have to worry about post title mismatches.

Comment: Basically the logged in user has a business page that is the CPT that is part of the theme (I didn’t code it). When they complete an enquiry form, I want to pull through their business page link into the form. The name they use on the business title is the User Login. Their business url is the artist/business-name That’s the url I want to pull in. In almost all cases, the slug is the username. I can handle the ones that aren’t manually, although digging out their specific business page url would be better.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like my answer does what you want then...